# AWS SDK JS httpOptions timeout intermittently not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I have deployed an AWS Lambda function for reading and serving S3 files. AWS SDK JS is initialized with these options

```
awsS3CustomConfig = {
        maxRetries: parseInt(1),
        httpOptions: {
          timeout: parseInt(1000),
        },
      }
```

While sometimes the code is working fine an I am getting this timeout exception in Lambda logs

```
{"response":{"statusCode":500,"headers":{},"body":"{\"status\":500,\"timestamp\":\"2023-06-12T23:52:40.865Z\",\"description\":\"Connection timed out after 1000ms\",\"message\":\"generalError\",\"subErrors\":[\"TimeoutError\"]}"}}
```

Mostly I am getting this log from SDK

```
{"message":"[AWS s3 200 130.776s 1 retries] getObject({\\n  Bucket: 'aue1p1z1s3bd*****',\\n  Key: 'bright/listing/802315843012.json',\\n  VersionId: undefined\\n})"}`
```

There are two problems here

1. Why SDK didn't timeout even after more than 130 seconds (timeout is just 1 sec)?
2. Why SDK logging 200 status instead of raising timeout error?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting this log from SDK"? Where is that log coming from? It seems to be referencing an S3 bucket, so where is the code that is attempting to access that object? Is it in the Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, it's the Lambda function code that's trying to read the S3 object using AWS SDK. The log that I have shared above is generated by AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue after implementing httpOptions.timeout with aws-sdk, implementing [abort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#abort-property) method with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method of javascript fixed this issue for me.

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ maxRetries: 1 })

async function putObjectInS3(Bucket: string, Key: string, Body?: string, Tagging?: string): Promise<AWS.S3.Types.PutObjectOutput> {
  const params: AWS.S3.Types.PutObjectRequest = { Bucket, Key, Body, Tagging }

  const putObjectReq = s3.putObject(params)
  setTimeout(putObjectReq.abort.bind(putObjectReq), 3000) // 3 seconds timeout

  return putObjectReq.promise()
}
```

Please note that even though `abort` implementation works much better as compared to `httpOptions.timeout`, it also has chances to fail. I have noticed in my system it works 99.999% of times which is satisfactory for me.